# How to create a image local storage like a simple "cache"

Tags: android, json, image

I'm developing an Android application I have implemented a custom listview with a header (ImageView) and a content (different textview), all data the data are obtained from a json that contais all text and a link that directs to an image.

I have to implement a function that download images in a local folder and instead of downloading them from the internet to fetch from the local folder.

I have to problem :

1) I have to implement a function that download in local storage the images during the parsing of my JSON. If the parser found an image must be downlaoded.

2) After the parsing the downloaded images must be associated to the local images.

3) When i try to show all the data, the images must be showed from local.

(Actually I use volley to load images from internet)

How i can do this ? How i can maintain the link beetween images and data

```
    [
      {
        "date":"MY DATE",
        "desc":"My description",
        "id":"1",
        "img":"http:\/\/MYURL\/FOLDER\/homeone.jpg",
        "text":" My text",
        "title":"My title"
      }
   ]
```

***** EDIT 1 *****

I have a problem with Picasso library, I don't understand how I can implement the cache. For example, after the parsing of my JSON I can get the url of my JSON item.

In this case `http:\/\/MYURL\/FOLDER\/homeone.jpg` now I have to save the image to he local storage.

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .into(imageView);
```

This is the code that I have found in another question on StackOverflow, this could help me to create the cache ? If yes, how i can specify the cache folder ?
Is is possible only save the images on local storage ? This cache is "permanent" or all data will deleted when the application is re-started ?

Comment: Give unique ids for your data and images and save relations in SQLite table.

Or you can store data by yourself and use `com.squareup.picasso` [library](https://github.com/square/picasso) to download and cache images by respective urls.

Comment: Please, look at my edit 1

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achive is implemented in  [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Try to avoid wheel inventing :)

UPD:
Picasso cache images automatically and you don't need to care about this thing at all. However, you can try this example to setup cache manuallly.
This is how you can define your cache with a help of OkHTTP:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(readTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        File cachePath = FuncFileDownload.getStoragePath(context, "pre");
        client.setCache(new com.squareup.okhttp.Cache(cachePath, 30000000));

        sPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
                .build();
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(sPicasso);
```